# problem reading a excel spreadsheet xml document

Tags: java, excel, xml

`enter code here`I have a homework that needs to read in JAVA a XML document, but the problem is that the XML generated document hasnt got getElementbytagName, because the file is a excel spreadsheet type of XML, so when i did XPath for that it leads to error

here is the document: https://www.juntadeandalucia.es/datosabiertos/portal/dataset/91f3c95b-a2d2-4828-8880-99f8ea156d0e/resource/f7737217-65d6-4b00-bd10-2f82c69ae2f7/download/contratos-adjudicados-oct-23.xml

i need the data from  and pass to a Data Base but since i cant get the items i couldnt import to a Data Base

and i cant export the  excel file into pure XML since i need to use from this URL.

I tried SAX DOM ApacheIO but the problem is i dont know how to get the tag because there is not

```java
File inputfile = new File("C:\\Users\\qwerty\\Desktop\\file\\example.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = (Document) builder.parse(inputfile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      
        
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String elements = "/Worksheet/Data";
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(elements).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        
        for(int i = 0; nodeList.getLength() > i;i++){
            Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
            
            if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("worker:" + eElement.getAttribute(""));
                System.out.println(": " 
                + eElement.getElementsByTagName("").item(0).getTextContent());
                
                System.out.println(": " 
                + eElement.getElementsByTagName("").item(0).getTextContent());
                
                System.out.println(": " 
                + eElement.getElementsByTagName("").item(0).getTextContent());
                
                System.out.println(": " 
                + eElement.getElementsByTagName("").item(0).getTextContent());
            }
```

Comment: It's impossible to solve your problem without knowing exactly what you did and exactly how it failed, but my guess would be that you ignored the fact that all the elements are in namespaces. Telling us you got an error without saying what you did or what the error was means you aren't thinking clearly about your strategy for problem solving.

Comment: okay i did. The XML document is not a pure XML(link i provided) so i cant find the tagName therefore i cant make it to show in the output

Comment: Isn't it "//Workbook/Worksheet/Row/Cell/Data" for the XPath value ? 

Because if the XML file shows up in your internet browser, the XML file is valid.

Comment: ty i will try but since it doesnt have a tagname only "Data", and not for example: <Name>, <FirstName> etc i cant put it into a data base

Comment: You're failing to account for the default namespace in your XPath.  See the duplicate link for further information on this common mistake.